# External Service to create user in Azure returns Bad Request

Tags: external-services, openapispecification

Okay here is a tough one. I am playing around with External Services to connect to the Azure (Microsoft Graph) API.

I can confirm that my named credential is working and I am successful in querying data.

However, when I try to create a user I get the following response:

> The MIME type 'text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2'
> requires a '/' character between type and subtype, such as
> 'text/plain

Bizarre thing is that the user is successfully created in Azure which leads me to the point that it must be something in my response headers. See below my OpenAPI Specification:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Microsoft Graph API List User Endpoint",
    "version": "v1.0",
    "description": "API to list all users in the organization"
  },
  "servers": [{
    "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "description": "Production server"
  }],
  "components" : {...},
  "parameters" : {...}
  "paths":{
    "/users":{
         "post":{
            "summary":"Create User",
            "description":"Create a new user in the organization.",
            "requestBody":{
            "description":"The request body contains an object representing the user to be created.",
            "required":true,
            "content":{
                "application/json; chartset=UTF-8":{
                   "schema":{
                    "$ref":"#/components/schemas/UserCreate"
                   },
                   "example":{
                      "accountEnabled":true,
                      "displayName":"Adele Vance",
                      "mailNickname":"AdeleV",
                      "userPrincipalName":"AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                      "passwordProfile":{
                         "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn":true,
                         "password":"xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          "responses":{
             "201":{
                "description":"Created",
                "content":{
                   "application/json":{
                      "schema":{
                         "$ref":"#/components/schemas/User"
                      },
                      "example":{
                         "businessPhones":[
                          
                         ],
                         "displayName":"Sample Sample",
                         "givenName":null,
                         "jobTitle":null,
                         "mail":"s.Sample@Sample.com",
                         "mobilePhone":null,
                         "officeLocation":null,
                         "preferredLanguage":null,
                         "surname":null,
                         "userPrincipalName":"Sample.com#EXT#@j4rvis.com",
                         "id":"Sample-a2a3-4ba2-ab7b-64044312a790"
                      }
                   }
                }
             },
             "400":{
                "$ref":"#/components/responses/400"
             },
             "401":{
                "$ref":"#/components/responses/401"
             },
             "403":{
                "$ref":"#/components/responses/403"
             },
             "404":{
                "$ref":"#/components/responses/404"
             },
             "500":{
                "$ref":"#/components/responses/500"
             }
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to call the API via apex and it works without issues. Appreciate anyone's insight.

Comment: Does this related [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005H4EIAU) help?

Answer (score 0):

i'd say that currently your accept header in the request that you're sending is not correct. thus you are getting the error.
From what you are showing you should be accepting application/json but we don't have a hand on your request headers.
you could try to look into this...

something like :

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/some_path');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setbody('yourBody');
Map<String,String> headers = new Map<String,String>();
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); //here you set the accept
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am able to make the callout from Apex but I am using External Services. In my OAS JSON I am actually setting the accept header in the post.content.response.<type> path. Hence I am at a loss